# What does "Allow email notifications when I subscribe to questions or tags" mean?

Tags: support, tags, notifications, email, email-notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [E-Mail Notifications in StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/e-mail-notifications-in-stackoverflow)

This option is found in the preferences section of the user profile.
Additionally, how do you subscribe to a question or a tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you "Allow email notifications" then that means you will receive them. (Once subscribed to questions or tags)

To subscribe to a tag, click on [this link](https://stackexchange.com/filters), which can also be found under your favourite/ignore tag lists on the main page. Follow the instructions there.

I can't see how to subscribe to an individual question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The tag filters link you provide has its own email option. So what's the point of the email option I refer to? Also, why does the option I refer to contain the wording "subscribe to questions" if its not possible to subscribe to questions?

Comment: @osm maybe the email link in the profile is for added configurability — to not get emails from all the sites in your filter. The filter subscribes to questions or tags, but not individual questions, so maybe that's what the message means

Comment: Wrong. The correct answer is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142193/152859)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd how is it wrong, or even different?

Comment: You will not receive any email unless you perform crucial step of "If you click the Stack Exchange logo at the top left, and click Email settings, you can configure responses to be sent to you" that is described in the other answer, so your first sentence is pretty much wrong as far as I can see.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the first line answers the title of the question.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Made it clearer in your post so it won't confuse others. :)