# Notification to OP when a new answer is posted in response to his/her question

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering why OP is not notified when someone answers his/her question.Same situation happened to me when I posted a question in stackoverflow and waited for couple of hours but no one posted in reply and the other day when I logged into my account I found that my question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985181/how-to-create-pkg-file-using-applescript).Even some question which I answer the OP responds 2 days later. [Here is one such situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432267/why-uitextfield-has-to-be-populated-for-uibutton-to-disappear-as-subview/14433597#14433597)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get notified with a small red icon next to the StackExchange button.

[image: Notification]

If you want to be notified by email, you need to enable the email notification. You have that option both when submitting the question, and after you have submitted it.

[image: Email notification]

Comment: Do I have to enable that for every question I put up?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli See the answer to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/e-mail-notifications-in-stackoverflow