# How does one get email notifications from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, notifications, stack-overflow

I've never once received an email notification in response to questions I've posted here at Stack Overflow. So I always go back to my question and refresh the page to see if anybody answered.

One person said if I mark the question as a favorite that would do it. But unfortunately that doesn't help.

How do we get notifications?

Comment: Personally I get an email notification every four hours if I have unread comments to my posts, or answers to my questions. At any time, notifications show up in the top left area (inside the SE logo). I don't know if it's a setting, though, I can't remember. Also, belongs on Meta.

Comment: Hmm.. Under meta it looks like they are arguing more than anything else. :)

Comment: @Doug indeed, the whole point of Meta is to discuss things and part of discussion is arguing. :)

Comment: I have the same problem. I got an e-mail notification from the Documentation only once or twice, but after that no notifications :(

Comment: The problem is still there. I never get email notifications

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestion by @yUnoDOWNVOTE, also go to account preferences, click on "Manage newsletter subscriptions".   Make sure "#3 Do you want email updates when new questions arrive in this filter?" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your preferences have e-mail notifications set up. Alternatively, the bar on the top left provides real-time updates, which is the method I usually use. (StackExchange button - has inbox, notifications, and a couple of other things.)

Also, questions like these should be directed to meta.stackoverflow.com - please take a moment to check out all of the different exchange sites available. Webmasters, Meta, etc.

Comment: In preferences the "Allow email notifications when I subscribe to questions or tags" box is checked. The bar at the top left requires leaving the browser open, right? Or is this something else. I will check the "meta" link suggested above too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but if you're actively coding it's no big deal. You may need to check your e-mail settings to make sure it isn't going into spam. I think you subscribe when you ask, answer, or favorite. As long as it's on in pref you should get the e-mails.

Comment: I just checked my Gmail spam box and it's not in there. And it looks like it is set to deliver mail every 3 hours, but I've never gotten a thing. Ever. Mail is nice because you can get it anywhere and see, "Oh! I have an answer! I'll go check and see if there is a good solution." Anyway, if the top left notifier thingie is all there is that's all there is I guess.