# Why didn't I get a notification about an answer to my question?

Tags: support, notifications, email-notification

Yesterday I posted this question:

["Collapse" left-aligned breadcrumb and centered header into single line, but only if they don't overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727264/collapse-left-aligned-breadcrumb-and-centered-header-into-single-line-but-onl)

1 hour later, that is 20 hours ago, an answer was posted. I didn't receive an email notification for that, and yes, I have checked my Spam folder.

Why is that?

Comment: What are your email settings set too? (To look at your email settings, got to settings, then click edit email settings).

Comment: or use the direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current

Comment: 3 hours minimum wait, and must not check notifications: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355567/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171051/282094

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly due to your email settings?

[image]

Comment: Wow. I assumed the default was to get an email *immediately* when I get an answer to a question (and since I never touched that I assumed that was my current setting). Not only is that not the default, it doesn't even exist as an option! Then, I don't see any setting for (or even indication of) WHEN the daily email is sent (btw I'm not even finding a timezone setting in the profile, but I must be missing that). Finally, one single setting for all "inbox"-related notifiications and that's it? I cannot decide to be notified e.g. for answers but not comments? Very poor configuration options.