# Can we have instantaneous e-mail notifications?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

Due to the interactive nature of the StackExchange sites it would be nice for less active users to receive e-mail notifications whenever an answer or comment is posted, both for questions asked and questions answered. This has already been discussed in the following answers:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142193/314652
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270409/1283667

One alternative posted at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270410/1283667 (which was unfortunately down-voted by someone) is to use the Android app which will display the notifications very quickly. But I don't think this alternative would work for everybody.

Another alternative is to use the new Chrome browser notification feature to notify the user when a new answer or comment is posted to a question asked or answered. This would probably not work on all browsers but would be available on almost all desktop and laptop devices used by the Stack Exchange community.

Can we consider these and/or other alternatives to enable all users to receive instantaneous notifications?

Comment: This has been already [suggested and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6557/instant-e-mail-notifications-of-answers-to-questions) years ago.

Comment: If you merely  want notifications displayed somewhere, just leave the post open in a browser tab.

Comment: Just a comment that the same question has been asked a number of times but with no reason why the instantaneous e-mail notifications had been declined.