# How do I get emails when someone comments on my question?

Tags: support, email

How do I get emails when someone comments on my question?

I read that you need to click the Stack Exchange icon in the top left, but all I get are communities (*[Getting email notifications when comments or answers are posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/getting-email-notifications-when-comments-or-answers-are-posted)*).

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm more asking about the navigation part

Comment: Where did you "read that you need to click the stack exchange icon in the top left"?  Any question of less than a few sentences is highly prone to misinterpretation but at the moment this still seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @PolyGeo https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/getting-email-notifications-when-comments-or-answers-are-posted

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/10/08/improved-global-email-notifications/ answer you ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yes, that worked, thanks.  But I don't think I can mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: Cool if it work, will write it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see that blog post, they explain how to do it;

https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/10/08/improved-global-email-notifications/

To quote the blog, in case the blog post disappear;

> Our track record on email notifications has been mixed at best. Since
>   early 2009, we’ve had some forms of email notification, including:
>
> •A checkbox under each question you own, asking if you want email
>   notifications for that specific question.
>
> •A long since removed “oh, you’ve been away for 7 days, so we will
>   mail you any **new comments and answers to your questions** as a courtesy”
>   feature.
>
> To turn on email notifications, open your profile page by clicking
>   your name as it appears at the top of any Stack Exchange site, and
>   look for the “preferences” option at the top.
>
> In the settings, you can confirm your email address — we’ll validate
>   it in this case to make sure the emails will arrive — and specify
>   whether you want emails delivered daily, weekly, or every 3 hours.
>
> Bear in mind that we will only email you if you have not checked your
>   global inbox in that time interval. Meaning, if you select the default
>   of “daily”, and you don’t click to expand your global inbox on any
>   Stack Exchange site for a full 24 hour period… you’ll then get an
>   email delivered to you with the contents of your global inbox. And if
>   you don’t check for another 24 hours, you will get another email, and
>   so forth.